# Rust adding associated type with u32

Tags: rust

I have an associated type `MyType`.

This type is going to be an unsigned integer, but I use it because the size of the unsigned integer required for this variable is maybe going to change in the future. So `MyType` is going to be one of: `u32`, `u64`, `u128`.

So MyType will look like this when defined: `MyType = u32` (of course it may not be `u32`).

In my code, I need to increment this variable of type `MyType` by one.

so I have to do this: `let n: MyType = v + 1`, where v is the type of `MyType`.

How can I do this, what trait restrictions should `MyType` have?

I would want something like this: `type MyType: UnsignedInt`, but the problem is there is no number trait in rust as far as I have seen.

Comment: Are you asking about [plus operator overloading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/ops.html)?

Comment: @freakish well, yes.

Comment: @freakish but the other type is just u32(the ```1``` that I want to add to n)

Comment: @Brian I was using the wrong term, I don't want to implement a trait, I want to restrict the type of the ```MyType``` like this: ```type MyType: UnsignedInt```, but the problem is there is no number trait in rust as far as I have seen.

Comment: The [`num_traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/) crate should have everything you need.

Comment: @Szegoo as far as I understand (note that I'm not a Rust developer) you just need to `impl ops::Add<u32> for MyType`? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @freakish I think he does **not** want to hard-code `u32` into it. Remember, `u64` does **not** implement `ops::Add<u32>`. And `impl ops::Add<MyType> for MyType` wouldn't gain much, because it still wouldn't give him the ability to add `1`. I think `num_traits` really is the answer here.

Comment: @Finomnis I'm not sure I undertand, the `u32` refers to the type of literal `1`, not to the underlying numeric type of `MyType`, right?

Comment: Yes, the `u32` in your code refers to the literal `1`. But `u64` does not implement `Add<u32>`, so it couldn't be used for that.

Comment: @Finomnis I'm still new to Rust, so please bear with me. The literal `1` in the context of custom type `MyType` and `v + 1` expression actually is `i32`, correct? (earlier I used `u32`, but should've been `i32` if I'm not mistaken) If so, I can implement `impl ops::Add<i32> for MyType`. If the underlying type of `MyType` changes to, say `u64`, then all I need to do is to change implementation of `ops::Add<i32>` and add a cast/conversion from `i32` to `u64`, or whatever needs to be done. Isn't that so?

Comment: @freakish The `1` literal is typeless, it is whatever type it is being used as. If it is added to a `u32`, it is a `u32`. If it is added to a `u64`, it is a `u64`. If you want a typed literal `1`, you need to write `1u32` or `1i32`. I'm uncertain what happens with the literal if you add it to a custom type, but most certainly the compiler will simply be confused. That's why I would cast the `1` to the custom type first. And `num_traits` offers that functionality via the `FromPrimitive` trait.

Comment: @Finomnis this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dcc41297b0d304d981e15dfc484ce5a9 is what I had in mind. But I think I understand now where's the problem. The OP wants a type alias. And I was thinking about a new struct. Which btw sounds like a better design, at least for me.

Comment: @freakish he wants an *associated type*. That's a type alias inside of a trait.

Comment: @freakish But I have to agree that the question is worded very vaguely

Comment: @Finomnis oh, ok, *associated type* is something even different. Yes, I have to learn Rust properly. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is very vague and it would be much easier if you added a code example, but deriving from the word **associated type** I tried to reconstruct a minimal example:

```rust
trait Incrementor {
    type MyType;

    fn increment(&self, value: Self::MyType) -> Self::MyType {
        value + 1
    }
}

struct U32Incrementor;
impl Incrementor for U32Incrementor {
    type MyType = u32;
}

fn main() {
    let incrementor = U32Incrementor;

    println!("{}", incrementor.increment(10));
}
```

```
error[E0369]: cannot add `{integer}` to `<Self as Incrementor>::MyType`
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 |         value + 1
  |         ----- ^ - {integer}
  |         |
  |         <Self as Incrementor>::MyType
  |
  = note: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `<Self as Incrementor>::MyType`
```

Is that about the problem you are having?

If yes, does this help?

```rust
use num_traits::{FromPrimitive, One, Unsigned};

trait Incrementor {
    type MyType: Unsigned + FromPrimitive;

    fn increment(&self, value: Self::MyType) -> Self::MyType {
        value + Self::MyType::one()
    }

    fn increment_ten(&self, value: Self::MyType) -> Self::MyType {
        value + Self::MyType::from_u8(10).unwrap()
    }
}

struct U32Incrementor;
impl Incrementor for U32Incrementor {
    type MyType = u32;
}

fn main() {
    let incrementor = U32Incrementor;

    println!("{}", incrementor.increment(10));
    println!("{}", incrementor.increment_ten(10));
}
```

```
11
20
```

It's based on the excellent [num_traits](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/index.html) crate.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a trait like Unsigned and FromPrimitive, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator behavior is specified by the trait [`std::ops::Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Add.html). This trait is generic over its output type, so if you want for example `MyType` to have the semantics `MyType + MyType = MyType` you can write:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    type MyType: std::ops::Add<Output = Self::MyType>;
}
```

All integers will implement this. If you need additional operators you can use the traits from `std::ops`, but with multiple bounds this can become tedious. The crate [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits) can help you with pre-declared traits that has all required ops and more. For example the trait [`NumOps`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/trait.NumOps.html) specify all arithmetic operators, and there are more traits such as [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/trait.Num.html) that includes equality and zero/one or [`PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/int/trait.PrimInt.html) that specifies basically every operation or method integers in Rust have.